# Embedding PHP script inside XML string

Tags: php, xml, string, foreach

Hi I have code which fetches multiple file attachment details from database, Now I have to insert those details inside an XML string and use to for further code

Here is the code

```
<?php  
$FileAttachments = get_file_attachments();

$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="" xmlns:wsu="">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-EB0B39D982F3D3DFE714897582537972">
            <wsu:Created>'.$created_date.'.797Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-EB0B39D982F3D3DFE714897582496061">
            <wsse:Username>Testuser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password*1</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ns0:process xmlns:ns0="">
         <ns0:Incident>
            <ns2:FileAttachments>
               <ns2:FileAttachmentList>
                  <ns2:Data/>
                  <ns2:FileName>FileName</ns2:FileName>
                  <ns2:ID id="677"/>
                  <ns2:Description></ns2:Description>
               </ns2:FileAttachmentList>
            </ns2:FileAttachments>
         </ns0:Incident>
      </ns0:process>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' ;

echo $xml;
?>
```

the function `get_file_attachments()` returns file ID, File name and description. I want to put a loop inside the  xml string to embed those fields in to it.

```
 <ns2:FileAttachments>
               <ns2:FileAttachmentList>
                  <ns2:Data/>
                  <ns2:FileName>FileName</ns2:FileName>
                  <ns2:ID id="677"/>
                  <ns2:Description></ns2:Description>
               </ns2:FileAttachmentList>
            </ns2:FileAttachments>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the issue here? You put all that into a php file and output an xml document. Just like you would normally output a html document. You want to add some content type header too.

Comment: The issue is to embed the foreach loop inside xml string to loop through results and send them

Comment: Sure, but that is exactly the traditional usage of php _embedded_ inside markup, typically html. But you can obviously do exactly the same when creating xml or any other language.

Comment: your title not match your question. please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through attachments first, then embed the result into the xml. e.g.:

```
$attachments = '';
for(...) {
    $attachments .= <<<END_XML
       <ns2:FileAttachments>
           <ns2:FileAttachmentList>
              <ns2:Data/>
              <ns2:FileName>$filename</ns2:FileName>
              <ns2:ID id="$id"/>
              <ns2:Description></ns2:Description>
           </ns2:FileAttachmentList>
        </ns2:FileAttachments>
END_XML;
}
$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="">
<soapenv:Header>
.....
       <ns0:process xmlns:ns0="">
         <ns0:Incident>
' . $attachments . '
         </ns0:Incident>
      </ns0:process>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' ;
```